# DB2 "FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY" does not work in a db2 stored procedure

Tags: db2

DB2 Version: **10.5.x** 
The following query works fine: 
`db2 "SELECT * FROM <table> FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"`

But when I use the same statement in a db2 stored procedure, it throws error 
`db2 "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sampleStoredProc() BEGIN DELETE FROM <table> WHERE TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 ','00:00:00 ') + CAST ( SUBSTR(TIMESTAMP, 1, 10) AS INTEGER ) SECONDS < (CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) FETCH  FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY ;` 
Error from DB2: 
**DB21034E**  *The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "FETCH  2 ROW ONLY" was found following "RENT
DATE - 90 DAYS)".  Expected tokens may include:  "<\space>".  LINE NUMBER=1.*
**SQLSTATE=42601**

If I remove the `FETCH  FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` line, then it works fine. Also, the above stored procedure works fine in db2 11.x. So, is there some bug in DB2 10.5.x which is not allowing me to create the stored procedure?

Comment: The SQL syntax changes between versions! The Db2-LUW v10.5 DELETE syntax does not allow the fetch-clause, while the Db2-LUW v11.x DELETE syntax allows it. You will need to change the query for Db2-LUW v10.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [V10.5 DELETE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=statements-delete) statement doesn't allow the `FETCH FIRST` clause, but the [V11.1 DELETE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-delete) one does allow it.
You may use the following syntax in Db2 10.5:

```
DELETE FROM 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM <table> 
  WHERE 
       TIMESTAMP ('1970-01-01 ', '00:00:00') 
     + CAST (SUBSTR(TIMESTAMP, 1, 10) AS INTEGER) SECONDS
     < (CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS)
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
)
```